# Interpolate nodata in rasters using Python

Tags: python, raster, gdal, interpolation, rasterio

I have a raster of the shape (1000,1000) and some areas having no data values. I would like to fill the data gaps by interpolating or tinning (does not matter) over the surrounding areas, however I fail to do that using Python.

I have searched tried some procedures already discussed at stackexchange, but failed to succeed:

**Attempt 1: using gdal.FillNodata**

```
import gdal, gdalconst
file = "C:\\Foo\\bar.tif"


raster = gdal.Open(file, gdalconst.GA_Update) 
fill = raster.GetRasterBand(1)
f = gdal.FillNodata(targetBand = fill, maskBand = None, maxSearchDist = 50, smoothingIterations = 0)

fill= fi.ReadAsArray()
geotransform = raster.GetGeoTransform()
originX = geotransform[0]
originY = geotransform[3]
pixelWidth = geotransform[1]
pixelHeight = geotransform[5]
cols = raster.RasterXSize
rows = raster.RasterYSize
driver = gdal.GetDriverByName('GTiff')
outRaster = driver.Create("D:\\Foo\\out.tif", cols, rows, 1, gdal.GDT_Float32)
outRaster.SetGeoTransform((originX, pixelWidth, 0, originY, 0, pixelHeight))
outband = outRaster.GetRasterBand(1)
outband.WriteArray(fir)
outRasterSRS = osr.SpatialReference()
outRasterSRS.ImportFromEPSG(4326)
outRaster.SetProjection(outRasterSRS.ExportToWkt())
outband.FlushCache()


### does not work - it takes ages, even with a smaller example. And if it works, there are no changes compared to the input file
```

**Attempt 2: Using rasterio.fill** -- However, this returns an AttributeError.

**Attempt 3: Using Scipy**

```
import tifffile
from scipy.interpolate import griddata

raster = tifffile.imread("D:\\Foo\\bar.tif")

grid_x, grid_y = np.mgrid[0:1000, 0:1000]

nans = np.argwhere(np.isnan(raster))
coordnotnan = np.argwhere(~np.isnan(raster))
valuenotnan = excr[coordnotnan]
vanona = valuenotnan[:,0,0]

grid_z1 = griddata(coordnotnan,vanona,nans, method=nearest) #for sake of testing

grT = grid_z1.T
rR= list(raster.ravel())
new = []
i = 0
for na in rR:
    if np.isnan(na) == True:
        new.append(grT[i])
        i += 1
    else:
        new.append(na)

arrayed = np.array(new, dtype=np.float32).reshape((1000,1000))
#...
## Besides being inefficient (loops), it does not seem to take the values of the neighboring pixels
```

Do you spot the mistakes I've made? Is there another way to get this job done?

Answer (score 3):

rasterio "fill" function is worked for me. using rasterio 1.1.0

```
import rasterio
from rasterio.fill import fillnodata

tif_file = r"D:\dem.tif"
with rasterio.open(tif_file) as src:
    profile = src.profile
    arr = src.read(1)
    arr_filled = fillnodata(arr, mask=src.read_masks(1), max_search_distance=10, smoothing_iterations=0)

newtif_file = r"D:\dem_filled.tif"   
with rasterio.open(newtif_file, 'w', **profile) as dest:
    dest.write_band(1, arr_filled)
```