# Python interpolation analogues of gdal.Grid

Tags: python, raster, gdal, shapefile

I want to make from .shp a raster by the following code:

```
    gdal.Grid(raster,
              shapefile,
              algorithm='invdist:power=15',
              format='GTiff',
              width=976,
              height=1966)
```

The size of the raster may be even more, depending on the input .shp file. Overall, it took about 8 hours only to achieve 30% of the rasterization! It's too slow in my case! Can anyone suggest another tool or optimization to the existing one without touching resolution and input point number?

P.S. The number of features is equal to 3 085 319
P.P.S. The best solution, for now, is the answer from here: [Interpolate nodata in rasters using Python](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/361575/interpolate-nodata-in-rasters-using-python)

Comment: The default for Weighting power is 2. Have you tried if process is faster with that?

Comment: The result that I want to achieve is appropriate when the power is equal to 15. But I checked it without size stating. Now I launched stating both - size and power = 2 and yes, it does calculate faster. Let me wait for the final result.

Answer (score 1):

For a reference timing from my test with gdal_grid executable (GDAL 3.3) on Windows. I took the Liechtenstein OSM extract from Geofebrik.de and converted data into SpatiaLite database. Layer "points" had 15286 features

My command

```
gdal_grid -a invdist:power=15 -of GTiff -outsize 976 1966 -l points liechtenstein.sqlite points.tif
```

Processing took 6 minutes and 10 seconds. With power=2 processing was much faster and took only about 20 seconds with my test data.

Comment: my feature count is 3 085 319

Comment: Maybe gdal_grid does not handle so big dataset fast enough. Iterate with increasing number of points and consider other tools. Perhaps some point cloud utilities would be better for you.

Comment: Yeah, but I'm asking which alternative can be :) I need it no use in pair with python

Comment: * I need it TO use in pair with python. Typo, sorry.

Comment: Perhaps you should edit the title of your question to describe your problem better so that interpolation specialists would find it. GRASS at least can do IDW https://grass.osgeo.org/grass79/manuals/v.surf.idw.html.